# Sync Token Exception google-api-client-service php people Service

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-people-api

I have a problem with the Google API.  I need to get all the contacts of a user in my application, however I don't want to load all the data each time, because I store the data in my database.

It's why I want to use the Sync Token functionality which let's us get only data who has been changed since our last query.

For this i Use the [Google APIs PHP client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

I wrote my code and it throws an exception (Google_Service_Exception) which explains that my Sync Token is not valid anymore, so I decided to use a try/catch system to reset syncToken if it is not valid.

My problem is each time i made the request I go in the catch (the google_service_exception) is raised even if my token is valid.

I store the token in my database so I tested it in the API explorer here: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list and it work fine, so I don't understand why my application doesn't work properly.

Here's my code:

```
    $personFields = 'metadata,names,addresses,biographies,birthdays,emailAddresses,genders,memberships,organizations,phoneNumbers';
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $syncToken = $user->getContactSyncToken();
    $nextPagetoken = '';
    $contactData = array();

    $people_service = new \Google_Service_PeopleService($client);

do {

        try {
            $data = $people_service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections(
                'people/me',
                array(
                    'personFields' => $personFields,
                    'requestSyncToken' => true,
                    'syncToken' => $syncToken,
                    'pageToken' => $nextPagetoken,

                )
            );
        }catch (\Google_Service_Exception $e){
            $data = $people_service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections(
                'people/me',
                array(
                    'personFields' => $personFields,
                    'requestSyncToken' => true,
                    'syncToken' => '',
                    'pageToken' => $nextPagetoken,

                )
            );
        }finally{
            $syncToken = $data->getNextSyncToken();
            $nextPagetoken = $data->getNextPageToken();
            if (count($data->getConnections()) != 0) {
                $contactData[] = $data->getConnections();
            }
        }




    }while ($nextPagetoken !== null);

$user->setContactSyncToken($syncToken);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
return $contactData;
```

Thank you for your help and sorry for my english i'm not a native and not very good at it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i found the problem, in my User class i had:

```
public function getContactSyncToken()
{

    if($token = $this->contactSyncToken  !== null){
        return $token;
    }else{
        return '';
    }
    }
```

And it always return ' ', now it works with:

```
public function getContactSyncToken()
{
    $token = $this->contactSyncToken;
    if($token  !== null){
        return $token;
    }else{
        return '';
    }


}
```